QGIS - Measure 5km from polygon intersection with river network
I have a river network which spans multiple countries (MultiLineString format), with the vector direction always towards downstream.
Overlaid on this is a polygon layer. I need to calculate 5km up or downstream the segments (measuring along the vector) from the intersections with the polygon layer when a segment has a certain range in one field (mean discharge), and 10km for all other values.
Ideally this would then be able to be included in a model, therefore I would ideally avoid using the LRS plugin which is not usable in the graphic modeler.

I know you have tagged this as qgis but if you have ArcPro then RivEX can generate a variety of reaches from snapped points.
